# Error al correr: php public/index.php en proyecto Zend

Tags: zend

Soy nuevo usando Zend, tengo un proyecto, el cual se me pide correr por consola de Ubuntu de la siguiente forma: **php public/index.php**, pero al ejecutar esa línea me muestra: **"Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided"**. Ya intente usar tipo de rutas, zf-console, incluso ya corrí las rutas como: **zf <mi_ruta>**, pero me dice que el nombre de la ruta no es un comando.

Agradecería si alguien me pueda orientar. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No debes preocuparte. Siempre sale esa respuesta mientras no añadas comandos específicos, tuyos o de terceros, que suelen salir en la misma consola cuando ejecutas el `index.php`.

Añado un par de capturas de muestra, por ejemplo con el cli de Doctrine:

1ª captura, cuando ejecutas el `index.php` sin comandos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2ª captura, cuando ejecutas el `index.php` con comandos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, en cuanto tienes comandos disponibles y funcionando correctamente ese mensaje sale siempre que no le des instrucciones específicas a la consola.

Comment: Gracias @OscarR es correcto estaba ingresando un comando que no tengo en mi proyecto.

Comment: @estebanaliyañezbadillo cualquier consulta que tengas no dudes en pasar por aquí. Y si te sirvió la respuesta, se agradece que la aceptes y la puntúes si lo estimas oportuno. Saludos.

Comment: agradezco tu ayuda, creo que por que tengo poco tiempo no me deja puntearla, pero ya la acepte y en cuanto se pueda la punto. saludos.